# Why use OAuth in mobile HTML5 application that will use REST?

Tags: authentication, mobile, oauth

I am exploring the possibilities of a banking mobile HTML5 application. It will be contacting with the main server via RESTful API. Very often I hear that people are using OAuth in their mobile apps to access APIs. For example, SpringSource's [html5expense](https://github.com/SpringSource/html5expense) demo app.

So I don't fully understand why bother? Couldn't the user just login in a standard way, receive a cookie with session id (or in case of Play framework, session data), that will be used to identify user when the app makes requests to REST?

Answer (score 2):

Oauth is usually a lot more secure than most BASIC AUTH, or "logging in in a standard way" approaches (and OAuth is becoming more and more of a standard).

When you login, through most "standard" ways, the user enters his username & password, into the application, and username/password are then often either stored locally, or transferred to the application, to then potentially be relayed to a "main server" that for example provides the API. So the user will have to enter his very secret login information (e.g. for banking?), into a client, app or system he doesn't know or trust...

With OAuth, the user is directed to a login page of the owner of that API .. e.g. his bank for example, where he logs into the secure login page that he knows and is asked for his consent that the application "xyz" would like to access his data.... The application that has requested that access, is then given a token with which it can access the API without needing to know the username and password. That way the username/password is only entered once, at a location the user trusts.

Furthermore, the user could later log into and admit page .. (the bank app? or and admin frontend), and delete the given access right to the API, and so stop an application accessing his information, without having to change his password.

Beyond the effect of being actually safe, using something like OAuth, for a banking app also makes sense as it will give people more confidence if modern security techniques are applied. It makes it also feel safer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to publish your API to third party developers; there really is no reason to bother with OAuth.

The biggest reason OAuth exists is to enable integrations with your API without your users having to give out their username and password to a third party. Other reasons is that it makes it possible to put a time frame on third party access to resources, or to scope access.